# silverlight - open xaml in new web browser

Tags: silverlight, xaml

In my silverlight application I want to open a xaml in a new web browser. how can I do that?
with HTMLPage.Window.Navigate it is just aspx pages - maybe I can convert xaml to aspx?

10x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a XAML page cannot be shown in a browser window.  What Silverlight do actually is showing the Silverlight program within an < object > tag in the aspx (or html) page; nothing more.

In your silverlight project, if you chose to host your project in a new web site, you will see a second project with both a htm and aspx file that hosts that object that links to your xap file.

So basically, you need to create a second Silverlight project that will be hosted in a different aspx page.  Then in your main silverlight project your can open that new aspx page in a new web browser window.